# How to filter objects based on a field in parent model

Tags: django, filtering

I want to find the therapist that have visited the patient.
my visit model:

```
class visit(models.Model):
    customer_name=models.ForeignKey(customerprofile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    therapist_name=models.ForeignKey(therapistProfiles, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
```

The first query works fine but it cannot find the matching query for the second one:

```
@property
def getthefee(self):
        customer = customerprofile.objects.get(c_name=self.customer_name)
        therapist=therapistProfiles.objects.get(name=self.therapist_name)
```

So I used this filtering:

```
therapist=therapistProfiles.objects.distinct().filter(name__contains=str(self.therapist_name)[0:10])
```

It works well but when I change the string length to 11 or longer it returns None.

The therapist model has a one to one relationship to users model but
customer model not.

```
class customerprofile(models.Model):
   c_name= models.CharField(max_length=40,  null=True, blank=True)

class therapistProfiles(models.Model):
   user=models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
   name=models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: add the respective models too (at least a few relevant fields), we can't help with queries if we're not sure of the fields in your models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the visit model the customer_name and therapist_name are instances of customerprofile and therapistprofile.

You can replace them as below:

```
class visit(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(customerprofile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    therapist = models.ForeignKey(therapistProfiles, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
```

You can directly access the related fields and their attributes without needing to fetch the objects using get()